# If and Else statement are both running in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

running a simple search and replace script, and i wrote an if statement that if the string **AKA user input** is empty, to alert "no string" but instead the else runs which is the function AND THEN the alert runs

```
let str = ''; // Testing if statement
let findWord = prompt('what word do you want to find');
let replaceWith = prompt('replace with that new word');

const searchAndReplace = (string, oldWord, newWord) => {
      if (string == '') { // should it be '', or null, or undefined?
            alert('no msg')
      } else {
            return string.split(oldWord.toLowerCase()).join(newWord.toLowerCase());
      }
}

let newString = searchAndReplace(str, findWord, replaceWith);
console.log(newString);
```

sorry in advance if this is a noob question, tried looking through here already

Comment: As a note, using `prompt` to get input is pretty crusty. Why not two input fields and a button?

Comment: "*instead the else runs which is the function*" - How do you know?

Comment: Either you're running this function twice, or you're not. Check with your debugger by setting a breakpoint in both.

Comment: @tad i just chose prompt out of laziness, if you think that might be the cause of my trouble then i'll test with input and submit

Comment: I think it's just going to be super annoying for you to have to test this. You can click a button on a form a dozen times with a pre-populated value, it takes zero effort. Typing in stuff takes effort.

Comment: Seems to be working as expected, [see for yourself here](https://jsfiddle.net/as97LaxL/)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
if (!string || string === '')
```

in javascript null, undefined, or even empty are false.
hope it helps.

Comment: The empty string is false as well, so it's rather pointless to spell it out - it could be shortened to `if (!string)`. But why do you think this is a problem in the OPs code?

Comment: i tried it but the else statement still runs first and then the if statement runs

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.
I'm not sure why you think both IF and ELSE is executed.

When the string is empty, your code execute IF statement, and do nothing else. Not returning anything == return undefined.

```
function Test1() {
    console.log("I return undefined, not null");
}

var test1 = Test1();
console.log("Test 1 is ? ", test1); // Test 1 is ? undefined

function Test2() {
    console.log("I return string");
  return "test2-string";
}

var test2 = Test2();
console.log("Test 2 is ? ", test2); // Test 2 is ? test2-string
```

[image: string is empty]

[image: Else statement only]

```js
let str = ''; // Testing if statement
let findWord = prompt('what word do you want to find');
let replaceWith = prompt('replace with that new word');

const searchAndReplace = (string, oldWord, newWord) => {
      // should it be '', or null, or undefined?
      console.log("input value: ", string, oldWord, newWord);
      if (string == '') { 
          console.log("IF it's empty");
          alert('no msg');
      } else {
          console.log("ELSE string is not empty");
          return string.split(oldWord.toLowerCase()).join(newWord.toLowerCase());
      }
};

let newString = searchAndReplace(str, findWord, replaceWith);
console.log("newString: ", newString);


console.log("=========================");


function Test1() {
  console.log("I return undefined, not null");
 }

 var test1 = Test1();
 console.log("Test 1 is ? ", test1); // Test 1 is ? undefined

 function Test2() {
  console.log("I return string");
   return "test2-string";
 }

 var test2 = Test2();
 console.log("Test 2 is ? ", test2); // Test 2 is ? test2-string
```